# Html2pdf and jsPdf - Table headers are not repeating in next pages while generating the pdf

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

Html2pdf and jsPdf - Table headers are not repeating in next pages while generating the pdf

Refer the code example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xcrjpe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html

**Expected Results:**
Table Headers should display on each page while click on **EXPORT TO PDF** button

Comment: Read this: [ask]